# Picasso crashing on app startup

Tags: picasso, okhttp

I'm trying to use Picasso with disk caching.  To do so, I understand I need to include the okhttp and okio libraries.  When I do so, I get the following:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.4'

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method source(Ljava/io/File;)Lokio/Source; in class Lokio/Okio; or its super classes (declaration of 'okio.Okio' appears in /system/framework/okhttp.jar)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.DiskLruCache.readJournal(DiskLruCache.java:243)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.DiskLruCache.open(DiskLruCache.java:224)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Cache.<init>(Cache.java:146)
        at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.<init>(OkHttpDownloader.java:74)
        at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.<init>(OkHttpDownloader.java:51)
        at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.<init>(OkHttpDownloader.java:41)
        at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$OkHttpLoaderCreator.create(Utils.java:407)
        at com.squareup.picasso.Utils.createDefaultDownloader(Utils.java:255)
        at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$Builder.build(Picasso.java:605)
        at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.with(Picasso.java:482)
```

This is with a brand new app.

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Switching to okhttp 1.6.0 seems to solve the crash.  Although I'm still not able to get disk caching working

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the Okio dependency, it's transitive.

The problem is that the L preview was improperly packaged and incorrectly exposed Okio on the system classpath. All crashes from this can be ignored completely as a function of pre-release software. The actual L release will not behave this way.

More details are available at https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/967